# Screenreaders fail to read out checkbox label on mobile browsers

Tags: google-chrome, safari, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

Been running into some screenreader issues with both Mobile Chrome + TalkBack, as well as Mobile Safari + Voiceover. Thought it might have been my code at first, but encountered the same problems running the following code on a page with no other JS/CSS loaded:

```html
<body>
<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="test" value="foo">
<label for="test" id="test-label">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</label>
<button id="button" onclick="(function() { document.getElementById('test').focus(); })()">test</button>
</body>
```

The issues encountered are similar in that they're focus related, but different in how they manifest.

**In Mobile Chrome**
If you turn TalkBack on and tap the button, focus will get set to the checkbox, and the label will be read the first time around, but will fail to do so on subsequent button taps. This seems to happen because the accessibility focus does not get updated on subsequent taps, and stays focused on the button, while the actual `document.activeElement` focus is set on the checkbox.

**In Mobile Safari**
This one gets really weird. Like in Chrome, with Voiceover on, the first time generally works as expected, but on subsequent button taps, the label is only partially read out before it gets abruptly cut off, with the focus sometimes (oftentimes) moving up to the address bar.

Would appreciate any insight into this, given that these are native checkboxes: it seems to be like these are bugs with the screenreaders/mobile browsers themselves.

Comment: I tried the example on my iPhone and can confirm it works the first time but subsequent times start to read the checkbox label but then the VO focus is moved to the address bar.  How bizarre!  (Note, I couldn't see the "run code snippet" button from iOS so I copy/pasted the code to a simple page to test.)  There is nothing obviously wrong with your code so I would contact Apple.  Not sure about android/talkback.

Comment: Yeah, I contacted them about it, but it really is the oddest thing. I found a really hacky workaround to it in the meanwhile using a intermediary text field.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior with android isn't surprising. Jaws and NVDA behave more or less the same on desktop browsers.

When using a screen reader, you must distinguish between the system focus, and the place where the user is currently looking at, they aren't always the same.

When system focus is moved programmatically or by pressing tab, the reading position is put at the same place as the system focus.
But when the user reads the page by pressing arrow keys, quick navigation keys such as H to go to the next heading, or on mobile devices by sweeping or using things like the rotor, only the reading cursor is moved while the system focus stays in place.

On the second button press, since the system focus isn't really moved to a new place, the reading cursor isn't moved where the system cursor is.
No move, no interruption to read what's in the new position.
This explains the generally consist behavior that you have observed.

However, for iOS Safari, it clearly seems to be a bug.
I have no definite answer here, but seeing how VO cuts off the label, it might well be related to its exagerated length.

Comment: Ah I think I follow what you're saying: you're saying system focus is still on the checkbox despite the secondary button presses, right? That's true if you've screen reader swiped over from the initial programmatic focus to the button, but I was testing this by using a combination of click/tap/swipe, and through breakpoints, did see that the `document.activeElement` was getting updated to be the button on click, before getting set back to the checkbox. So it seems more that the screen reader focus isn't always following the screen reader focus.

Comment: In principle, screen reader always follows system focus, except when using special review modes. But as you have yourself experimented, when clicking on a button with something else than the keyboard, the system focus is briefly set on the button before immediately going back to the previous place.
So when you set programatically the focus to the checkbox after the click on the button for the second time, it is already back on the checkbox...

Comment: Ah to be clear, what I meant was that at the moment the onClick/onSubmit handlers were run, `document.activeElement` was correctly set to the button itself, and was then moved to the checkbox after I programmatically set it (not automatically)